# What is the difference between branch-0.2 and origin/branch-0.2 in Git?

Tags: git, branch

I cloned a Git repository and when I do a 'git checkout' I see branch-0.2 and origin/branch-0.2 in the list of the branches. What is the difference between the two branches? I read a couple of articles, but I'm not clear on what the difference is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`origin/branch-0.2` is the local reference to `branch-0.2` in the remote named `origin`. It is also called a remote-tracking branch. You can synchronise it (for manual merging later using `git merge`) with the remote by running: `git fetch origin branch-0.2`. In order to fetch and merge at the same time, you can use: `git pull origin branch-0.2`.

Comment: To add some info: If you just do a `git fetch` you just download objects that were changed on the remote version of the branch. The `branch-0.2` still points to your changes. If you want to merge in the changes you'd need to issue `git merge origin/branch-0.2` to be back in sync. This is automatically done if you do `git pull`

Comment: I'm afraid there's an element of your answer that's not correct: `git fetch origin branch-0.2` doesn't update `origin/branch-0.2`, it just points `FETCH_HEAD` to where `branch-0.2` points to in `origin`.  Personally, I would only ever use `git fetch` in the form `git fetch <remote>`, which updates all the remote-tracking branches from `<remote>`, which is usually what you want.